# I am getting an error when I am checking npm version

Tags: apt, bash, nodejs, javascript

I am getting an error when I hit `npm -v`. Actually this happent after I tried a command to update my npm version from 3.5.2 to version 4 or higher. The command I used:

```
sudo ln -sf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Now, as soon as I hit the `npm -v`, it is throwing an error saying

> bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory

After this I un-insatlled node and re-insatlled but it's not working. Please help me.

Comment: you created symbolic link from `user` to `superuser` ignoring its dependencies. You need to unlink it `sudo unlink /usr/bin/nodejs`